# Names of my JTable columns not showing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created a `JFrame` with Java Swing using a `BorderLayout`. Both east and west layout are fixed with some components, while `BorderLayout` at the center can change depending on what the user does. At the beginning there is a picture,

```
panelDinamycCenter = new JPanel ();   
JScrollPane = new JScrollPane (panelDinamycCenter);

panelDinamycCenter.add (new JLabel ( "", new Imagelcon ( "......."),  JLabel.CENTER));

jFrame.getContentPane (). add (JScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then a data entry screen, for which I used a `GridBagLayout`. In order to remove the picture and to insert the new screen I used this:

```
panelDinamycCenter.removeAll (),
```

then I add the various components. After

```
setVisible (true);
```

I have now created a `JTable`, to be included in `panelDinamycCenter`,

```
panelDinamycCenter.removeAll ();

String [] [] matrixValori = new String  [arrayOggCreaJTableDeroghe.length] [arrayJTableNomeColumnDeroghe.length];

for (int i = 0; i <arrayOggCreaJTableDeroghe.length; i ++) {
    matrixValori [i] = arrayOggCreaJTableDeroghe [i] .creaArrayString ();
}

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel (matrixValori,    arrayJTableNomeColumnDeroghe);
JTable JTable = new JTable (model);
jTable.setAutoResizeMode (JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

panelDinamycCenter.add (JTable);

jFrame.setVisible (true);
```

All right, but I can not see the names of the columns. Why?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [*How to Use Tables: Adding a Table to a Container*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show), "The scroll pane automatically places the table header at the top of the viewport." At a  minimum, you need to replace the `JScrollPane` removed by `removeAll()`:

```
JTable jTable = new JTable(model);
panelDinamycCenter.add(new JScrollPane(jTable));
```

Among alternatives, consider these:

- Add the table header to  `PAGE_START`, as suggested [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show).
- Instead of removing and restoring, use [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to switch between views.